# Building URL Dynamically

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to build a URL dynamically, i have a product feature table which holds the url. The purpose of this exercise is for a user to click on a link;

www.domain.com/climbing-frames_rockwall/ then the user can click on another link www.domain.com/climbing-frames_rockwall_step-ladder (rockwall and step-ladder are individual features). Each time a user clicks on a link i need to append the next feature.

So far i have

```
<cfset filterURL = "" />
<cfif IsDefined('url.feat') AND url.feat NEQ "">

<cfquery name="geturl" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT txt_feat_url
FROM tbl_features
WHERE uid_features=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.feat#">
</cfquery>
<cfset filterURL = filterURL & "_" & geturl.txt_feat_url>
</cfif>
```

Its not appending though?

Jason

Comment: What do you mean by it's not appending? When you cfdump geturl.txt_feat_url do you get the expected value? What value does filterURL after trying to append?

Comment: Hi Barry Thanks for your response, i have a demo online http://cfukstaging.jasoncongerton.co.uk/get-features.cfm. I need the filterURL to build with every click of the filters on the side. They start with /climbing-frames_feature so when a user clicks this i need to update each url on the filter list with /climbing-frames_filterURL_feature etc. You will see what i mean on the page above.

Comment: The pages have been url rewritten with every feature re-written to the url param feat. so when a user clicks  on one of the feature filters and id is passed to the query geturl, it just needs to keep adding to the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `filterURL = ""` at the top. So, in the following line you are just appending geturl.txt_feat_url to a blank string:

```
<cfset filterURL = filterURL & "_" & geturl.txt_feat_url>
```

That is why you are ending up with values such as "_monkey-bar" instead of "climbing-frames_rockwall-ladder_monkey-bar".Where are you expecting the value of filterURL to come from, is it the URL scope?

Comment: Hi Barry, i have just reliased i was resetting the filterURL (numpty!). Every time a filter is clicked i get an id to re-run the geturl query which gives me the url for the drilled filter/feature i just need to store the previous filter/feature url and then add the new one to it. I really do appreciate your time, especially on a saturday!!

Comment: No problem, I enjoy finding solutions. If my answer was correct then you can show your appreciation by ticking it as such :) cheers

Comment: I just cant get this to work? It just wont build the url? Late night early start = brain dead!
`<!---create the url --->
<cfif Isdefined('filterURL') AND filterURL NEQ "">
<cfset filterURL = filterURL>
<cfelse>
<cfset filterURL ="">
</cfif>
<cfif IsDefined('url.feat') AND url.feat NEQ "">

<cfquery name="geturl" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT txt_feat_url
FROM tbl_features
WHERE uid_features=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.feat#">
</cfquery>


<cfset filterURL = filterURL & "_" & geturl.txt_feat_url>


</cfif>`

Comment: Hi Barry, not to worry i have sorted it! 

`<cfparam default="" name="filterURL">


<cfif addNew EQ "yes">
<cfif IsDefined('url.feat') AND url.feat NEQ "">

<cfquery name="geturl" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT txt_feat_url
FROM tbl_features
WHERE uid_features=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.feat#">
</cfquery>


<cfset filterURL = "_" & geturl.txt_feat_url>


</cfif>
<cfif Isdefined('session.myURL')>
<cfset session.myURL = session.myURL & filterURL><cfelse><cfset session.myURL = filterURL></cfif>
</cfif>`